predictive control model using GEKKO
I am modeling an MPC to maintain the temperature in a building within a given interval while minimizing the energy consumption. I am using GEKKO to model my algorithm.
I wrote the following code. First, I identified my model using data with the input (the disturbance: external temperature and the control), and the output y , which is the temperature. Then, I built an ARX model (using the arx function in GEKKO. This is my code :
# Import library 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# Initialize Model

ts = 300
t = np.arange(0,len(data_1)*ts, ts)
u_id = data_1[['T_ext','beta']]
y_id = data_1[['T_int']]

# system identification

#meas : the time-series next step is predicted from prior measurements as in ARX

na=5; nb=5 # ARX coefficients
print('Identify model')
start = time.time()
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u_id,y_id,na,nb,objf=100,scale=False,diaglevel=0,pred='meas')
print('temps de prediction :'+str(time.time()-start)+'s')

#%% create control ARX model

T_externel = np.array([5.450257,5.448852,5.447447,5.446042,5.444637,5.443232,5.441826,5.440421,5.439016, 
                       5.440421,5.437610,5.436205,5.434799,5.433394,5.431988,5.430583,5.429177,5.427771,
                        5.426365, 5.424959, 5.423553  ])

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance  
m.d = m.u[0] 


# distrubance and parametres 
m.d = m.Param(T_externel)   

# lower,heigh bound for MV
TL = m.Param(values = 16)
TH = m.Param(values = 18)
    

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # the objective is an l2-norm (squared error)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 1 # APOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*300,300) # step time = 300s


# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 1 # use measured value
m.beta.DMAX = 1.0  # Delta MV maximum step per horizon interval
m.beta.DCOST = 2.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0
m.beta.MEAS = 0    # set u=0


# Controlled variables
m.T.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.T.FSTATUS = 1       # receive measurement
m.T.options.CV_TYPE=2 # the objective is an l2-norm (squared error)
m.T.SP = 17           # set point


TL.values = np.ones(len(T_externel))*16
TH.values = np.ones(len(T_externel))*18
m.T.value = 17 # Temprature starts at 17

for i in range(len(T_externel)):
    m.d = T_externel[i]
    m.solve(disp = False)
    
    if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
        # Retrieve new values
        beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL

    else:
        # Solution failed
        beta  = 0.0



I get the following error :
  File c:\algoritmempc\gekko_mpc.py:84
    m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (0,) 

I also have another question. Since one of my inputs is a disturbance, I'm not sure if the way I declared my variables is correct or not (I want to provide the disturbances myself).

@ John Hedengren I really appreciate your support. Could you please help me solve this problem?

When creating a question, please include example data that reproduces the error. It appears that the code is correct with this randomly generated data:
# Example data for data_1
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
n = 100  # Number of data points

# Generating example data
T_ext = np.random.uniform(low=5, high=25, size=n)
beta = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n)
T_int = T_ext * 0.5 + beta * 10 + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=n)

# Create DataFrame
data_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'T_ext': T_ext,
    'beta': beta,
    'T_int': T_int
})

I've also made minor corrections so that T_externel is correctly defined for the steady-state initialization (one value) and for the model predictive control application.
# Import library 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from gekko import GEKKO

# Example data for data_1
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
n = 100  # Number of data points

# Generating example data
T_ext = np.random.uniform(low=5, high=25, size=n)
beta = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n)
T_int = T_ext * 0.5 + beta * 10 + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=n)

# Create DataFrame
data_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'T_ext': T_ext,
    'beta': beta,
    'T_int': T_int
})

# Initialize Model

ts = 300
t = np.arange(0,len(data_1)*ts, ts)
u_id = data_1[['T_ext','beta']]
y_id = data_1[['T_int']]

# system identification
m = GEKKO()

#meas : the time-series next step is predicted from prior measurements as in ARX

na=5; nb=5 # ARX coefficients
print('Identify model')
start = time.time()
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u_id,y_id,na,nb,objf=100,scale=False,diaglevel=0,pred='meas')
print('temps de prediction :'+str(time.time()-start)+'s')

#%% create control ARX model

T_externel = np.array([5.450257,5.448852,5.447447,5.446042,5.444637,5.443232,5.441826,5.440421,5.439016, 
                       5.440421,5.437610,5.436205,5.434799,5.433394,5.431988,5.430583,5.429177,5.427771,
                        5.426365, 5.424959, 5.423553  ])

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.y = m.Array(m.CV,1)
m.u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,m.y,m.u)

# rename CVs
m.T = m.y[0]

# rename MVs
m.beta = m.u[1]

# distrubance  
m.d = m.u[0] 

# distrubance and parametres 
m.d = m.Param(T_externel[0])   

# lower,heigh bound for MV
TL = m.Param(value = 16)
TH = m.Param(value = 18)
    
# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.d.value = T_externel 

m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # the objective is an l2-norm (squared error)
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 1 # APOPT
m.time = np.arange(0,len(T_externel)*300,300) # step time = 300s

# Manipulated variables
m.beta.STATUS = 1  # calculated by the optimizer
m.beta.FSTATUS = 1 # use measured value
m.beta.DMAX = 1.0  # Delta MV maximum step per horizon interval
m.beta.DCOST = 2.0 # Delta cost penalty for MV movement
m.beta.UPPER = 1.0 # Lower bound
m.beta.LOWER = 0.0
m.beta.MEAS = 0    # set u=0

# Controlled variables
m.T.STATUS = 1        # drive to set point
m.T.FSTATUS = 1       # receive measurement
m.T.SP = 17           # set point

TL.value = np.ones(len(T_externel))*16
TH.value = np.ones(len(T_externel))*18
m.T.value = 17 # Temprature starts at 17

for i in range(len(T_externel)):
    m.d = T_externel[i]
    m.solve(disp = False)
    
    if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
        # Retrieve new values
        beta  = m.beta.NEWVAL

    else:
        # Solution failed
        beta  = 0.0

I recommend the Temperature Control Lab (TCLab) for learning about model predictive control with ARX models. This is a heat transfer application, similar to the home application where there is an external temperature (T2) that can be used as a disturbance, and internal temperature (T1) that can be used as the internal temperature. This code uses TCLabModel() (digital twin) that can be switched to TCLab() if you have the device. It demonstrates MIMO MPC, but you could switch T2 to the disturbance.

import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import json
# get gekko package with:
#   pip install gekko
from gekko import GEKKO
# get tclab package with:
#   pip install tclab
from tclab import TCLab

# Connect to Arduino
a = TCLabModel()

# Make an MP4 animation?
make_mp4 = False
if make_mp4:
    import imageio  # required to make animation
    import os
    try:
        os.mkdir('./figures')
    except:
        pass

# Final time
tf = 10 # min
# number of data points (every 2 seconds)
n = tf * 30 + 1

# Percent Heater (0-100%)
Q1s = np.zeros(n)
Q2s = np.zeros(n)

# Temperatures (degC)
T1m = a.T1 * np.ones(n)
T2m = a.T2 * np.ones(n)
# Temperature setpoints
T1sp = T1m[0] * np.ones(n)
T2sp = T2m[0] * np.ones(n)

# Heater set point steps about every 150 sec
T1sp[3:] = 50.0
T2sp[40:] = 35.0
T1sp[80:] = 30.0
T2sp[120:] = 50.0
T1sp[160:] = 45.0
T2sp[200:] = 35.0
T1sp[240:] = 60.0

#########################################################
# Initialize Model
#########################################################
# load data (20 min, dt=2 sec) and parse into columns
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_2sec.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['Time']
u = data[['H1','H2']]
y = data[['T1','T2']]

# generate time-series model
m = GEKKO()

##################################################################
# system identification
na = 2 # output coefficients
nb = 2 # input coefficients
print('Identify model')
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,objf=10000,scale=False,diaglevel=1)

##################################################################
# plot sysid results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$H_1$',r'$H_2$'])
plt.ylabel('MVs')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.legend([r'$T_{1meas}$',r'$T_{2meas}$',\
            r'$T_{1pred}$',r'$T_{2pred}$'])
plt.ylabel('CVs')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()

##################################################################
# create control ARX model
y = m.Array(m.CV,2)
u = m.Array(m.MV,2)
m.arx(p,y,u)

# rename CVs
TC1 = y[0]
TC2 = y[1]

# rename MVs
Q1 = u[0]
Q2 = u[1]

# steady state initialization
m.options.IMODE = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

# set up MPC
m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 1 # Objective type
m.options.NODES   = 2 # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
m.time=np.linspace(0,120,61)

# Manipulated variables
Q1.STATUS = 1  # manipulated
Q1.FSTATUS = 0 # not measured
Q1.DMAX = 50.0
Q1.DCOST = 0.1
Q1.UPPER = 100.0
Q1.LOWER = 0.0

Q2.STATUS = 1  # manipulated
Q2.FSTATUS = 0 # not measured
Q2.DMAX = 50.0
Q2.DCOST = 0.1
Q2.UPPER = 100.0
Q2.LOWER = 0.0

# Controlled variables
TC1.STATUS = 1     # drive to set point
TC1.FSTATUS = 1    # receive measurement
TC1.TAU = 20       # response speed (time constant)
TC1.TR_INIT = 2    # reference trajectory
TC1.TR_OPEN = 0

TC2.STATUS = 1     # drive to set point
TC2.FSTATUS = 1    # receive measurement
TC2.TAU = 20        # response speed (time constant)
TC2.TR_INIT = 2    # dead-band
TC2.TR_OPEN = 1

##################################################################
# Create plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

# Main Loop
start_time = time.time()
prev_time = start_time
tm = np.zeros(n)

try:
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        # Sleep time
        sleep_max = 2.0
        sleep = sleep_max - (time.time() - prev_time)
        if sleep>=0.01:
            time.sleep(sleep-0.01)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.01)

        # Record time and change in time
        t = time.time()
        dt = t - prev_time
        prev_time = t
        tm[i] = t - start_time

        # Read temperatures in Celsius 
        T1m[i] = a.T1
        T2m[i] = a.T2

        # Insert measurements
        TC1.MEAS = T1m[i]
        TC2.MEAS = T2m[i]

        # Adjust setpoints
        db1 = 1.0 # dead-band
        TC1.SPHI = T1sp[i] + db1
        TC1.SPLO = T1sp[i] - db1

        db2 = 0.2
        TC2.SPHI = T2sp[i] + db2
        TC2.SPLO = T2sp[i] - db2

        # Adjust heaters with MPC
        m.solve() 

        if m.options.APPSTATUS == 1:
            # Retrieve new values
            Q1s[i+1]  = Q1.NEWVAL
            Q2s[i+1]  = Q2.NEWVAL
            # get additional solution information
            with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
                results = json.load(f)
        else:
            # Solution failed
            Q1s[i+1]  = 0.0
            Q2s[i+1]  = 0.0

        # Write new heater values (0-100)
        a.Q1(Q1s[i])
        a.Q2(Q2s[i])

        # Plot
        plt.clf()
        ax=plt.subplot(3,1,1)
        ax.grid()
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T1sp[0:i+1]+db1,'k-',\
                 label=r'$T_1$ target',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T1sp[0:i+1]-db1,'k-',\
                 label=None,lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T1m[0:i+1],'r.',label=r'$T_1$ measured')
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v1.bcv'],'r-',\
                 label=r'$T_1$ predicted',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v1.tr_hi'],'k--',\
                 label=r'$T_1$ trajectory')
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v1.tr_lo'],'k--')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature (degC)')
        plt.legend(loc=2)
        ax=plt.subplot(3,1,2)
        ax.grid()        
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T2sp[0:i+1]+db2,'k-',\
                 label=r'$T_2$ target',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T2sp[0:i+1]-db2,'k-',\
                 label=None,lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],T2m[0:i+1],'b.',label=r'$T_2$ measured')
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v2.bcv'],'b-',\
                 label=r'$T_2$ predict',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v2.tr_hi'],'k--',\
                 label=r'$T_2$ range')
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,results['v2.tr_lo'],'k--')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature (degC)')
        plt.legend(loc=2)
        ax=plt.subplot(3,1,3)
        ax.grid()
        plt.plot([tm[i],tm[i]],[0,100],'k-',\
                 label='Current Time',lw=1)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],Q1s[0:i+1],'r.-',\
                 label=r'$Q_1$ history',lw=2)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,Q1.value,'r-',\
                 label=r'$Q_1$ plan',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[0:i+1],Q2s[0:i+1],'b.-',\
                 label=r'$Q_2$ history',lw=2)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time,Q2.value,'b-',
                 label=r'$Q_2$ plan',lw=3)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time[1],Q1.value[1],color='red',\
                 marker='.',markersize=15)
        plt.plot(tm[i]+m.time[1],Q2.value[1],color='blue',\
                 marker='X',markersize=8)
        plt.ylabel('Heaters')
        plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
        plt.legend(loc=2)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.05)
        if make_mp4:
            filename='./figures/plot_'+str(i+10000)+'.png'
            plt.savefig(filename)

    # Turn off heaters and close connection
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    a.close()
    # Save figure
    plt.savefig('tclab_mpc.png')

    # generate mp4 from png figures in batches of 350
    if make_mp4:
        images = []
        iset = 0
        for i in range(1,n-1):
            filename='./figures/plot_'+str(i+10000)+'.png'
            images.append(imageio.imread(filename))
            if ((i+1)%350)==0:
                imageio.mimsave('results_'+str(iset)+'.mp4', images)
                iset += 1
                images = []
        if images!=[]:
            imageio.mimsave('results_'+str(iset)+'.mp4', images)

# Allow user to end loop with Ctrl-C           
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Turn off heaters and close connection
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    a.close()
    print('Shutting down')
    plt.savefig('tclab_mpc.png')

# Make sure serial connection still closes when there's an error
except:           
    # Disconnect from Arduino
    a.Q1(0)
    a.Q2(0)
    a.close()
    print('Error: Shutting down')
    plt.savefig('tclab_mpc.png')
    raise


Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. However, the data contains 8 million rows, which is why I couldn't includ it. When I test with the data you generated, it works, but with my data, I always get the same error

Can you reproduce the error with 10 or 100 rows if you truncate the data set?

@ John Thank you again for your response. I have reduced the data size as you suggested (10 rows and 100 rows), but I am still getting the error :     if u==[]:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (0,)

@ john I tried running it on Google Colab and it worked. I no longer have the error. However, the algorithm gives me beta values of 0 even though the output does not match the reference

Please create a new question for the new issue. If possible, include a minimal and reproducible example that gives the wrong behavior.

@ John  Thank you again, sir. Also, I have asked another question with figures for the command and the output obtained. link
